# Different picture display in real device and emulator Android

Tags: android, imageview, emulation

Different picture display in real device and emulator Android, I do not understand what is the reason

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/music"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:cropToPadding="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is how it looks on an emulator and a real device

[image: Emulator]
[image: Real device]

I enclose code Layout. I will be glad of any help

Comment: It looks like the same bitmap is being shown in each view. The layout is slightly different - is that what you mean?

Comment: On a real device on each side there is a space

Comment: use android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: so you want to remove that margin ? in real device

Comment: @Charef Eddine Mechalikh, yes

Comment: @Bojan Kseneman, It did not help

Comment: try my answer because i tested in tablet and it was good ,  just change the "centerCrop" and set it to the value you want , or let it as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your picture `height` and `width` are set to  `wrap_content` ,
try this ,but you need a high resolution picture , see **Harsh Dattani**'s answer about picture sizes and your problem should be solved

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"<!--changed this-->
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"<!--changed this-->
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/music"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"<!--added this line-->
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maintaining density independence is important because, without it, a
>   UI element (such as a button) appears physically larger on a
>   low-density screen and smaller on a high-density screen. Such
>   density-related size changes can cause problems in your application
>   layout and usability.

As perfectly documented in [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) docs, you need to support multiple screen size devices. There will be separate `Drawable` folders targeting various densities, place your image with specific density in respective folder.

A set of six generalized densities:

1. ldpi (low) ~120dpi
2. mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
3. hdpi (high) ~240dpi
4. xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
5. xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
6. xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Comment: I have one image and I want to use it.

Comment: Use android:adjustViewBounds="true" as ImageView attribute.